# CMV - How can I zoom in further using ArcGIS online basemaps?

Tags: arcgis-online, configurable-map-viewer

I need to be able to zoom in further in my cmv web map but I can't figure out where this is set. Any suggestions on where to look? I am also wondering if it is possible for opacity in these basemaps.

Answer (score 1):

The zoom levels (aka Levels of Detail or LODs) available for a map ares determined by the first layer that is loaded by the map. Typically this is the `basemap` you define in the `mapOptions` section of your `viewer/config.js` file. The levels are defined within the map service referenced in the basemap. For example, if you used `basemap: 'streets'`, the levels of detail would be 0 through 19 (20 total levels) based on this service: http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services/World_Street_Map/MapServer

The other ArcGIS Online basemaps are listed here: http://services.arcgisonline.com/arcgis/rest/services

I don't believe that you can set the opacity of a basemap within the configuration. You might be able to do this using CSS.

Comment: Thank you for your response. So I guess this means that I cannot zoom in as far as I can in ArcMap?

Comment: That is correct if you use the ArcGIS Online basemaps. You have more options if you use your own basemaps.